# ReactJS: Why isnt Material-UI <DatePicker/>'s property defaultDate working?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am using the `<DatePicker/>` from Material-UI ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker ) and trying to set the property `defaultDate` to the current date on my computer, but it is not displaying anything.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

**Here is the code:**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    //Followed the example from the link provided: So hoping to display today's date on my computer, which is 2016-09-29

    const dateToday = new Date();
    dateToday.setFullYear(dateToday.getFullYear())
    dateToday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

    this.state = {
      controlledDate: null,
      dateToday: dateToday,
    }
  }

  handleDateChange = (event, date) => {
    this.setState({
      controlledDate: date,
    });
  };

render() {
return (
  <DatePicker
      autoOk={true}
      defaultDate={this.state.dateToday}
      hintStyle={styles.hintLabel}
      value={this.state.controlledDate}
      onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    />
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through MUI's DatePicker Properties documentation and reading the `defaultDate` prop's description, which says:

> This is the initial date value of the component. If either `value` or `valueLink` is provided they will override this prop with `value` taking precedence.

Analyzing your component's code, you are setting the props `value` by passing to it `this.state.controlledDate` which is initially `null` thus taking precedence over the `dafaultDate` props you're trying to set.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const dateYesterday = new Date();
  dateYesterday.setDate(dateYesterday.getDate() - 1);

  this.state = {
    controlledDate: null,
    dateYesterday: dateYesterday
  };
};

handleDateChange = (event, date) => {
  this.setState({
    controlledDate: date,
  });
};

render () {
  return (
    <DatePicker
      autoOk={true}
      defaultDate={this.state.dateYesterday}
      // value={this.state.controlledDate}
      onChange={this.handleDateChange}
    />
  );
}
```

In this example I'm trying to set the initial date to yesterday's date but I commented the `value` prop to make it work, because otherwise the `value` prop would take precedence over the `defaultDate` prop I'm setting here with yesterday's date and so it wouldn't work. I'm guessing you don't really need to set `value` prop here.

Comment: It's not working. I've tried it without value just like yours and the date is not showing